# Galaxy S2 stuck at boot. Please help

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-2, clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop, kernel

Yesterday I flashed CM 12.1 on my Galaxy S2 gt-i9100. I rooted the device by flashing Siyah kernel via Odin. Then using cwm based siyah recovery I did the factory reset and wipe cache & dalvik and flashed CM. Everything went fine and my phone booted into CM. However, when I powered off the phone, and switched it on again, its stuck at the Samsung Galaxy S2 screen. I've been thinking but couldn't figure it out. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery, and if you can, does it work?

Comment: Yes, recovery works fine, cwm has been replaced by Cyanogen recovery.

Comment: Does booting from recovery change anything?

Comment: Nope, nothing whatsoever.

Comment: You are going to have to flash the ROM again and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Are you using a stable build of CM?